# CSOM CamlQuery won't return any file

Tags: caml-query, csom

I have a folder (Myfolder) 
that includes two subfolder2.

```
   Myfolder
    -----Subfolder1
    --------file1.zip
    --------file2.zip
    -----Subfolder2
```

Inside the subfolders there are zip files.
I cannot find them using a CamlQuery

```
string res = "";

List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Myfolder");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>" + 
                    "" +
                    "<Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>.zip</Value></Contains>" + 
                    "</Where></Query></View>";

ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(listitems);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem listItem in listitems)
{
    res += "" + listItem["Title"];
}

return res; // res is empty
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'ExecuteNonQuery`

```
var siteUrl = "/";
var res = "";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyFolder');    
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>" + 
                "" +
                "<Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>.zip</Value></Contains>" + 
                "</Where></Query></View>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();  
        res += " " + oListItem.get_item("FileLeafRef");
    }    
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    //Handle Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx) for specify  the server relative URL of a list folder from which results will be returned.

**Example**

Assume we need to retrieve zip files from Folder `Archive` located in `Documents` library

```
var fileType = "zip";
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
var query = new CamlQuery();
query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Documents/Archive";
query.ViewXml = string.Format(@"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>",fileType);
var items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["FileRef"]);
}
```

> Note: `File_x0020_Type` field is used in query to filter files by type